# Clicking an event from external source causes browser tab to reset

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I am using the example FullCalendar angular project to learn how to implement @fullcalendar and have setup a data server to fetch an array of events from a database.

The events are loaded, and displayed correctly (month/week/day view) but whenever I click an event, the browser reloads the page.

Events are loaded by updating the 'events' property:

```
this.dataService.getData('/events').subscribe(events => {
   this.calendarOptions.events = events;
});
```

Events added using the `CalendarApi.addEvent()` method do not produce the result and behave as expected.

**Current configuration:**

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.8
Node: 12.14.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.0.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: No

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.8
@angular/cli                      10.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.8
@schematics/angular               10.0.8
@schematics/update                0.1000.8
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.9.7
webpack                           4.43.0
```

**@fullcalendar packages installed:**

```
─┬ @fullcalendar/angular@5.4.0
├─┬ @fullcalendar/core@5.4.0
│ ├─┬ @fullcalendar/common@5.4.0
├─┬ @fullcalendar/daygrid@5.4.0
├─┬ @fullcalendar/interaction@5.4.0
├─┬ @fullcalendar/list@5.4.0
├─┬ @fullcalendar/timegrid@5.4.0
```

Proerties of an event added from a data source method:

```
{…}
​
_context: Object { dateEnv: {…}, options: {…}, pluginHooks: {…}, … }
_def: {…}
 allDay: true
 defId: "64"
 extendedProps: Object { eventTypeId: 1, contactName: "Test event 1 Contact", contactPhone: "Test event 1 phone", … }
 groupId: ""
 hasEnd: true
 publicId: "1"
 recurringDef: null
 sourceId: "62"
 title: "Test event 1"
 ui: Object { display: null, startEditable: undefined, durationEditable: undefined, … }
 url: "null"
 <prototype>: Object { … }
_instance: Object { instanceId: "65", defId: "64", range: {…}, … }
<prototype>: Object { setProp: setProp(name, val), setExtendedProp: setExtendedProp(name, val), setStart: setStart(startInput, options), … }
```

Proerties of an event added using Calendar.addEvent() method:

```
{…}
_context: Object { dateEnv: {…}, options: {…}, pluginHooks: {…}, … }
_def: {…}​​
 allDay: true
 defId: "78"
 extendedProps: {}
 <prototype>: Object { … }
 groupId: ""
 hasEnd: true
 publicId: "2"
 recurringDef: null
 sourceId: ""
 title: "vbnbn"
 ui: Object { display: null, backgroundColor: "red", borderColor: "red", … }
 url: ""
 <prototype>: Object { … }
_instance: Object { instanceId: "79", defId: "78", range: {…}, … }
<prototype>: Object { setProp: setProp(name, val), setExtendedProp: setExtendedProp(name, val), setStart: setStart(startInput, options), … }
```

Is anyone able to offer any suggestions why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue.

The issue was that the 'url' property was being set to null which was being returned from the query.

I have removed the url column from my db table and now it works correctly.